# Cloudformation fails to parse parameters - VolumeAttachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

I am trying to implement a Cloudformation template that will mount existing EBS volumes to Existing EC2 instances.
Here is the code i used:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: MountEBStoDev
Parameters:
  EBSVolumeID:
    Description: The volume we want to attach to the instances
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Volume::Id>"
  InstanceIdToMount:
    Description: The instance to attach the volume to
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Instance::Id>"

Resources:
 MountPoint:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment"
  Properties:
    Device: /dev/sdh
    InstanceId: !Ref InstanceIdToMount
    VolumeId: !Ref EBSVolumeID
```

When running the stack the user can choose the required EBS and EC2 instance, and i can see the the parameters are correctly specified after the selection but Cloudformation fails to attache the EBS with the error

> "Value of property InstanceId must be of type String"

I am suspecting the **List** in the parameter type as the culprit but i have found no other way to give the user the option to choose from available instances/EBS (aside from a static list).

Any help will be much appriciated.

Comment: How do you runinng the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `AWS::EC2::Instance::Id` and `AWS::EC2::Volume::Id` are [supported parameter types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types), so you could simply change your code to use those. Like so:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: MountEBStoDev
Parameters:
  EBSVolumeID:
    Description: The volume we want to attach to the instances
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Volume::Id"
  InstanceIdToMount:
    Description: The instance to attach the volume to
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance::Id"

Resources:
 MountPoint:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment"
  Properties:
    Device: /dev/sdh
    InstanceId: !Ref InstanceIdToMount
    VolumeId: !Ref EBSVolumeID
```

Comment: Thanks, That works but i am still getting an error with the device name
"Volume attachment between volume-id vol-xxxxxxxxxx and instance-id i-xxxxxxxxxxxxx at device /dev/sdh was not found". Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If your user select **only one instance and volume** (can't loop over multiple choices without a custom resource or a macro), then it should be:

```
Resources:
 MountPoint:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment"
  Properties:
    Device: /dev/sdh
    InstanceId: !Select [0, !Ref InstanceIdToMount]
    VolumeId: !Select [0, !Ref EBSVolumeID]
```

Comment: Looks like this solved the problem.
I now have a problem with the device name giving me the error "Volume attachment between volume-id and instance-id at device /dev/sdh was not found" will try to change the device name

Comment: @YaMo IanMckay's answer is better i think, so please check it and accept if possible. For the new issue, please make new question.